# How to save the value of a textbox defined in HTML file to a text file using Tagname

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I want to save the value of a textarea shown in webbrowser in a txt file
and I want to do this by GetelementbyTagName NOT GetelementbyID
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your webpage completed do some thing like:(for multi `textarea`)

```
  private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea "))
            {
               if(el.GetAttribute("ClassName")=="classname")
               {
                File.WriteAllText("address of file", el.InnerText);
               }
            }
        }
```

**Edited:**

for single`textarea`:

```
 foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea "))
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("address of file", el.InnerText);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not know why it does not work
 I need to define it in a button
what do I need to write instead of Classname?

Comment: not diffidence you can write it in button event,how may text area you have in your webbrowser control?

Comment: only 2,I do not know what is wrong but it still does not work
have you got any idea?

Comment: @Pedram:if you have more than one textarea in webbrowser set a class name for them or id.after you can simply get their text with its id or class name